# How do I destroy 4 Zerg Hatcheries in the "Zero Hour" mission on Hard difficulty?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a strategy to earn the best defense achievement in StarCraft 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/what-is-a-strategy-to-earn-the-best-defense-achievement-in-starcraft-2)

I'm working my way through some of the missions to get the extra achievements and learn some skills in the process, but I'm already having a hard time on the "Zero Hour" mission when playing on Hard.

**How do I destroy 4 Zerg Hatcheries on Hard difficulty?**

Is it a matter of going in quickly when they haven't gotten the change to built Spine Crawlers and other resistance? And should I focus on getting more SCV to pay for multiple Barracks?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/what-is-a-strategy-to-earn-the-best-defense-achievement-in-starcraft-2

Comment: How did he manage to not even name the mission, just as I missed the name of the achievement...?

Comment: I know it's years later but I just added the mission name into my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should check [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/what-is-a-strategy-to-earn-the-best-defense-achievement-in-starcraft-2)